# make that something -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

A scene from the movie [Pandorum (2009)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1188729/).
The Link to the audio file: http://tindeck.com/listen/guan (here's [the YouTube version](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1z4VBVaB7Fg#t=17m11s) with a time mark set to take you right to when the scene begins)

Two guys wake up from hypersleep and find themselves on a spaceship floating in space. They don't remember anything from the past and must figure out what to do. One of them crawls into a vent shaft while the other guy communicates with him via something like an advanced version of a walkie-talkie. A few minutes further into the scene, that guy falls out of an overhead compartment, gets up, realizes that it was an overhead compartment he fell out of and says this, "***make that an overhead compartment***."

I asked an English native speaker and he said this, *"he thinks he's in a locker on the floor but when he falls he realizes he was in an overhead compartment. Saying "make that a ____" is a common thing for jokes in movies like that.* That's as much as I've got so far, but I'd like to know more about this turn of phrase.

Comment: What does he say beforehand? In the context of a quote, *"make that a _____"* means, roughly, "let me change what I just said a moment ago." [M-W](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/make) has this example: _I'd like a hamburger. No, wait — make that a cheeseburger._ (Def. 5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"**Make that a/an...**" is a colloquial form of changing a former statement or request.

Your example:

> I'm in a (place 1) -> Make that a (place 2)

This works even when statement 1 was made by another person:

> Customer A, to waitress: "I'm having a beer"
>   Customer B, also to waitress: "Make that two."

(The underlying idea is that the waitress wrote down order no. one and now changes it.)

Later in the evening, you might overhear him adding a tip to the bill:

> Waitress: "That'll be $16. 
>   Customer: "Make that 20."